# How to delete particular lines in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a file as below, i want to search for this line `test name=""` and delete next 4 lines including the first one `test name=""`.

```
<test name="FT S_CREATE_DELETE_JOB">
<class name="11 .98. FT S_CREATE_DELETE_JOB">
COMPLETED
<test name="">
<class name="11.98.">
</class>
</test>
```

Comment: What line is "this line". Also, there are many ways in perl to do that, tried google yet to find code snippets?

Comment: Have you considered using an XML parser?

Comment: this line-> <test name="">

Comment: If you delete that line and the next four, that will leave you with `</class>\n</test>`... Sounds wrong to me.

Comment: no. i want to delete. <test name="">
<class name="11.98.">
</class>
</test>.. from above file

Comment: what? but that are the last 4, not the next 4

Comment: <test name="FT S_CREATE_DELETE_JOB">
<class name="11 .98. FT S_CREATE_DELETE_JOB">
COMPLETED
<test name="">
<class name="11.98.">
</class>
</test> from this i want to remove ,                            <test name="">
<class name="11.98.">
</class>
</test>

Comment: Please use the backticks to make your answer more readable .. `

Comment: @user1954970 If you remove an even amount of tags, the remaining tags are uneven. Or do you mean that there are closing tags for the two first lines?

Comment: Is this a complete file or are you just showing a small part of it?

Answer (score 2):

In most languages, you don't manipulate files directly. Instead, you open a second file, write your results there, and then rename the second file to the first and delete the original:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $input_fh, "<", "input.txt";
open my $output_fh, ">", "output.txt";
while ( my $line = <$input_fh> ) {
    chomp;
    last if $line eq '<test name="">';
    print {$output_fh} "$line\n";
}
close $input_fh;
close $output_fh;
unlink "input.txt";
rename "output.txt", "input.txt";
```

This is pretty basic stuff, so I suspect you don't know Perl. Maybe it's time to [learn it](http://learn.perl.org).